# multiphrase method with two phrases - Elastic Search

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, nest

I have a paragraph saying

> Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting
>   industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever
>   since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and
>   scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only
>   five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting,
>   remaining essentially unchanged.

Now i want to use match phrase for this paragraph with two phrases.

> 1.simply dummy text of the printing
>
> 2.make a type specimen book

Elastic search query should check if both these phrases are present in the paragraph and return answer. How can i do this?

Thanks in Advance.

My take on code:

```
{
    "query": {
        "match_phrase": {
            "paragraph": {
                "query": {"simply dummy text of the printing","make a type specimen book"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to do??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"AND" kind of conditions:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "paragraph": "simply dummy text of the printing"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "paragraph": "make a type specimen book"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

"OR" kind of conditions:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "paragraph": "simply dummy text of the printing"
          }
        },
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "paragraph": "make a type specimen book"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks andrei. If i dont want must and want to check if either of it is present then?

Comment: Then you need `should`.

Comment: Thanks Andrei for the immediate reply.. will try once.. :)

Comment: why is the score still not 1 if both the phrases are matching exactly? how are the scores given? can you please explain?

Comment: Because is more complicated than that. This explains some of it: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/scoring-theory.html. And you can see how ES is calculating the score if you add `?explain` to your query: `GET /my_index/my_type/_search?explain`

Comment: Thanks for the info Andrei.. Cheers!! :)

Comment: Hi andrei..small help.. if i have to use slop condition in the above query, where should i include it? should i add it after "paragraph" at both the places?